# Scrapy cannot be installed on windows with conda 3.5

Tags: python, windows, scrapy, conda

I have installed anaconda (python 3.5) and I wanted to install scrapy but i don't know why it's not working as you can take a look at my terminal but i don't know what is wrong

I used my powershell terminal because with conda I get other errors like

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda scrapy
  File "<ipython-input-1-dd63679531fb>", line 1
    conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda scrapy
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1426065) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You should run `conda install ...` from PowerShell, not from inside IPython.

Comment: I get this Error: too few arguments, must supply command line package specs or --file when I just put conda install . Alsoon my screenprint I use powershell and not ipython. the error comes from powershell

Comment: Well, the edited question now shows a different error message, not the one you asked about. At least you're now running conda install from the right place.

Comment: yes I made a screencap from powershell and it seems like it can't install scrapy

Comment: seems like scrapy is only for python 2.7 and not 3.5

Comment: @pengj, you should turn this comment into an answer.